# Вызов asm функции из кода на Си

Tags: c++, ассемблер, avr, atmel-studio

В проекте для AtmelStudio 7 пытаюсь вызвать asm функцию из кода на C++, но компилятор выдаёт ошибку

```
Error       ld returned 1 exit status
Error       undefined reference to `getpc()'
```

Вроде бы всё делаю правильно. Подскажите, в чём ошибка?

Файл `src/utils.S`. Код:

```
.global getpc

getpc:
    pop r16
    pop r17
    mov r24, r16
    mov r25, r17
    push r24
    push r25
    ret
```

Файл `main.cpp`. Код:

```
extern uint16_t getpc();
void main()
{
    uint16_t pc = getpc();
    while(1)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: файл src/utils.S нужно скомпилировать, получится src/utils.o файл. И вот его нужно подсунуть линковщику

Comment: Для крестов напишите `extern "C" uint16_t getpc();`

Comment: и не забывать пространство имён : в данном случае : `extern "C" { uint16_t getpc(); }`

Comment: @avp, благодарю Вас - помогло

Comment: обратите внимание: перепутаны `push` и `pop`, вызов функции испортит стек, хранящий адрес возврата